# Ajax json requests not working on chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome

I have an AJAX request of datatype JSON which sends data and receives JSON encoded data from PHP.
Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. In developers tool(chrome) it shows  `text/html` but shows `application/json` when added  `header('Content Type: application/json')` .
My question is why I have to use a header in chrome but not in firefox (in firefox it works fine)?
Another problem is that my AJAX requests are called on after another in firefox they work fine but in chrome it just runs once! Why?

```
function abc(){ 
  $.post('url.php',{  x : x },function(data){  
    //my stuff 
    setTimeout(abc,5000); 
  },'json'); 
}
```

in php

```
<?php 
  header('Content Type : application/json'); 
  //this not required in firefox.     
  echo json_encode(array("abc"=>$abc)); 
?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code that sends and receives the AJAX request/response?

Comment: I can give a same example!

`function abc(){
$.post('url.php',{
 x : x
},function(data){
 //my stuff
setTimeout(abc,5000);
},'json');
}`


in php
`<?php
header('Content Type : application/json'); //this not required in firefox.

   echo json_encode(array("abc"=>$abc));
?>`